# не работает inline-block в IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Ни в какую не хочет работать inline-block в IE11,
подскажите в чем может быть проблема? Скрин прилагаю. 
На другом компе в более древнем IE отображается нормально.

[image: скрин]

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/awDZGuUcqBNqR Explorer 11. Все норм

Comment: стоит проверить режим работы, возможно он показывает в режиме совместимости

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703017/ie-display-inline-block

Comment: @SkiesX Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 2):

Такая же беда была. Дело не в Open Serverе. IE работал в режиме совместимости в интрасети.

Настройки -> Параметры просмотра в режиме совместимости, Снять галку с работы в режиме совместимости в интрасети.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]